# Meaning of "up from"

Tags: grammar

> "Between July and May, ministries and divisions expended Tk 120,043
>   crore, up from Tk 98,978 crore in the same period a year ago. "

I don't understand the meaning of "**up from**" in the above sentence. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Would “having risen from” be clearer?

Answer (score 3):

In this case "up from" is a prepositional phrase that compares the current value (Tk 120,043 crore) to a past value during a similar period (Tk 98,978 crore)

If you put these numbers on a graph, 120,043 would be higher than 98,978 so it is "up." And since 98,978 is the past value, amound expended changed "from" that value.

This is a common way to compare numbers through the years/quarters/months.

> The US population is 327.2 million, up from 260.3 million in 1993

A similar phrase - "down from" - is also used if the value has decreased.